# Fail on that syntax .liquid (learning stage)

Tags: syntax-error, shopify, liquid

on my way to learn .liquid, i can't found issue on that syntax:

```
{{ 'visa.svg' | asset_img_url | image_url: width: 36, height: 36 | image_tag: alt: 'Visa', srcset: nil, class: 'filter-green', loading: 'lazy' }}
```

Fail: Liquid error (sections/footer.liquid line 264): invalid url input

Where is the fail? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because 'visa.svg' is not an image type object (nor 'visa.png' is).

asset_img_url returns URL and image_url expects image object. So there is a conflict "wrong input".

From [docs](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/url-filters#image_url):

> image_url Returns the URL of an image. You can use image_url on the
> following objects:
>
> product, variant, line, item, collection, article, image

[The Image Object](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/image)

> An image object returns information about an image. Image objects are usually attributes of other objects, such as product, variant, collection, and article.

Comment: i found some way to make it possible, it is something like this:           <img src="{{ 'visa.svg' | asset_url }}" width="36x" height="36x" class="filter-green" alt="Visa" loading="lazy" id="visa_svg" />

Comment: @ByGio1 yes, this is how it should be done :)